# Browser scrollbar issue when embedded with swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I am developing a flex application which is embedded in a html file. The issue is I am not able to get the browser scroll bars, once the browser window resizes. I have tried setting  overflow:scroll in the css code for html, but didn't work.

Consider an example like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="600" minHeight="400" width="100%" height="100%">
<s:BorderContainer left="30" right="30" height="120" width="100%" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" borderVisible="true">
<s:Label x="10" y="10" fontSize="12" fontFamily="Arial" fontStyle="normal" text="PCA title"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
<s:BorderContainer left="30" right="30" top="150" height="100%" bottom="30"  width="100%" backgroundColor="#000000" borderVisible="true">
</s:BorderContainer>
</s:Application>
```

Here if i set the absolute values for height and weight as height="768" and weight="1366", i do get the scrollbars. But i am developing the application using relative coordinates so that it works across all machines irrespective of their screen sizes. So, i cannot specify absolute value for height and weight.

Can someone help me with this as to how to get the scrollbars working without disturbing my relative coordinate system.

Comment: I am sorry, it is width="1366" and not weight="1366". And these parameters are set for the application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that I understand your question correctly, but I think you need [SWFFit](http://swffit.millermedeiros.com/).

This is a JavaScript tool that can limit the minimum and maximum sizes of the container of your Flash object, and will force the browser to supply scrollbars when required.

Comment: I need something which works like swffit. The reason i am not using swffit is because my application is very large and i do not want a situation where my application will have problem with swffit. Is there a way to get scrollers without swffit..?

Comment: you could just use CSS to set `min-width` and `min-height` properties on your container. Then if the browser contracts below these values scrollbars will appear.